# Error running build on device and registering for push notifications

Tags: ios, xcode6, apple-push-notifications

I am seeing this error after trying to register for push notifications when I build onto my device: `"no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement`

Based on some googling, I think this has to do with the provisioning profile not matching the bundle identifier for the app.  When I go to `Window > Devices > (Select my device) > "Show Provisioning Profiles"` I see that it is using a profile called this:

`iOSTeam Provisioning Profile:*`.

I've tried everything I can find, but can't track down the source of the issue or what I need to change to get this to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

P.S. I'm using Parse for push notifications, incase that is relevant.

I enabled push notifications:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Push Notifications for that AppId. So go to  developer.apple.com ->Identifiers -> Edit your appId and enable Push Notificaton.

While enabling push notifications you will create developer APNS Certificate.

[image]

Comment: I enabled push notifications for development, and downloaded the certificate, I see it in my keychain. Still getting the same error: `"no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"`